# SQL Server Another simple question

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 temp Tables `[Description]` and `[Institution]`, I want to have these two in one table.

---

They are both tables that look like this:

Table1; #T1

```
|Description|
blabla
blahblah
blagblag
```

Table2; #T2

```
|Institution|
Inst1
Inst2
Inst3
```

I want to get it like this:

Table3; #T3

```
    |Description|     |Institution|
    blabla             Inst1
    blahblah           Inst2
    blagblag           Inst3
```

They are already in sort order.

I just need to get them next to each other..

Last time I asked was something almost the same.

I used this query

```
Create Table #T3
( 
   [From] Datetime
   ,[To] Datetime
)

INSERT INTO #T3  
  SELECT #T1.[From]       
         , MIN(#T2.[To])
   FROM #T1   
   JOIN #T2 ON #T1.[From] < #T2.[To]   
   GROUP BY #T1.[From] 

Select * from  #T3
```

It did work for the date values, but it won't work here ? :s

Thank you.

Comment: You should really start using keys ...

Comment: Is `blagblag` in some way connected to `Inst3` or is it OK to pair `blagblag` with `Inst2` instead?

Comment: They are not connected, i need to get the values just next to eachother in different columns. Because i have ordered them before in a query, i dont need another order by, or join eachother on Id

Comment: "They are already in Sortorder" - they aren't. They really aren't. Tables don't *have* an order - that's one of the basic truths of SQL. Whilst simple tests with a few rows may suggest, e.g. that the results return in the same order in which they were inserted, that is *by no means* guaranteed. The only way to guarantee a particular order is to use `ORDER BY` - and in it's simplest form, that needs to be given a column by which to sort the rows.

Comment: So i should give first the Temp tables both id's
and in the last table i should join the id's with eachother?

Comment: You need a column in #T1 and in #T2 either to join the rows that should be together or something that can be used in an `order by`.

Comment: Ok i added ID'S For #T1 and #T2
And in #T3 I joined on the Id's. wich worked.

Comment: @Gigli that may partially solve your problem - it depends on how you're *populating* `#T1` and `#T2` now. The only way in which the assignment of IDENTITY values is guaranteed to occur in a particular order is if you're populating the values using the form `INSERT (...) SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY` (of course, the `WHERE` is optional). Without the `ORDER BY` being present there, there's no guarantee on which `ID` values will be assigned to the inserted rows.

Comment: I create the tables first myself with a query.
So i choose self wich value i put in the first row and second etc..
so i am sure they are in right order, i just pop in the id's .
cause i know they are in the right order

Comment: Ah, yes, if you're populating the tables in separate statements, a single row at a time, then yes, the identity values will match that. I'm so used to thinking set-at-a-time that I hadn't considered it.

Comment: @Gigli: No matter what you think now, or how you populate a table, **there is no order in SQL tables**. **No guarantee that they will be returned sorted** (in the order you think). Only if you use `ORDER BY`, you can have that guarantee. So, if you want to order the first table by the `Description` column and the second table by the `Institution` column, use @JohnD's answer (which uses those orders and adds rownumbers using those orders and then joins the tables).

Comment: Alternatively, you can join the tables using the `ID`s (that you added).

Answer (score 2):

One thing that concerns me is that you say that the values "are already in sort order".  There really is no default sort order -- if you don't specify a sort order, you are at the mercy of SQL Server to determine the order in which the data is returned.  The solution below assumes that there is some way to sort the data such that the records "match up" (using the ORDER BY clauses).

Hope this helps,

John

```
-- Table 1 test data
Create Table #T1
(
   [Description] nvarchar(30)
)
INSERT INTO #T1 ([Description]) VALUES ('desc1')
INSERT INTO #T1 ([Description]) VALUES ('desc2')
INSERT INTO #T1 ([Description]) VALUES ('desc3')

-- Table 2 test data
Create Table #T2
(
   [Institution] nvarchar(30)
)
INSERT INTO #T2 (Institution) VALUES ('Inst1')
INSERT INTO #T2 (Institution) VALUES ('Inst2')
INSERT INTO #T2 (Institution) VALUES ('Inst3')

-- Create table 3
Create Table #T3
( 
   [Description] nvarchar(30),
   [Institution] nvarchar(30)
);


-- Use CTE2 to add row numbers to the data; use the row numbers to join the tables
-- you must specify the sort order for the data in the tables
WITH CTE1 (Description, RowNum) AS
(
    SELECT [Description], ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY [Description]) as RowNum
    FROM #T1
),
CTE2 (Institution, RowNum) AS
(
    SELECT Institution, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Institution) as RowNum
    FROM #T2
)
INSERT INTO #T3
SELECT CTE1.Description, CTE2.Institution 
FROM CTE1
LEFT JOIN CTE2 ON CTE1.RowNum = CTE2.RowNum


Select * from  #T3
```